# Exception from HRESULT: 0xC00DABE8 when initializing MediaCapture

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, media

I'm trying to capture stream from external usb camera (C#, Windows 8). The following code:

```
DeviceInformationCollection devInfoCollection = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(DeviceClass.VideoCapture);
MediaCaptureInitializationSettings settings = new Windows.Media.Capture.MediaCaptureInitializationSettings();
settings.VideoDeviceId = devInfoCollection[0].Id;
mediaCaptureMgr = new MediaCapture();
await mediaCaptureMgr.InitializeAsync(settings);
```

In last line (await mediaCaptureMgr.InitializeAsync(settings)) is triggered exception.
The variable settings is not null.
settings:

> (VideoDeviceId ="\\?\USB#VID_05E3&PID_0510&MI_00#7&2D043328&0&0000#{e5323777-f976-4f5b-9b55-b94699c46e44}\GLOBAL")

Exception text:

```
Exception from HRESULT: 0xC00DABE8
Source  "mscorlib"
```

Ok. I tried to do such as:

```
try
{
   mediaCaptureMgr = new MediaCapture();
   await mediaCaptureMgr.InitializeAsync();
   myCaptureElement.Source = mediaCaptureMgr;
   await mediaCaptureMgr.StartPreviewAsync();

}
catch (Exception ee)
{
   String s = ee.ToString();
}
```

Anyway error occurs on the line (mediaCaptureMgr.InitializeAsync())
In this case: 
      s="System.Exception: Exception from HRESULT: 0xC00DABE8\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()\r\n   at TestVideo.MainPage.d__0.MoveNext() in c:\Users\Admin\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\TestVideo\TestVideo\MainPage.xaml.cs:line 53"

And Exception are same:"Exception from HRESULT: 0xC00DABE8"

Comment: This means "The current capture source does not have an audio stream".  Why your web cam is trying to capture audio is not clear from the question.

Comment: Have you tried with different hardware ?

Answer (score 0):

Please Set `StreamingCaptureMode` of  `MediaCaptureInitializationSettings` to video or audio according to the requirement like

```
settings.StreamingCaptureMode = settings.StreamingCaptureMode.Video;
```

I Hope this will help you